# How can I display fractions in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't find a clear answer or best practice on how to do this so I assume it's very easy. ;) I've seen some stuff about Unicode and been linked to some math libraries, but don't see anything obvious about how to *display* them. This is for an iOS app and I'm using Expo. I'm looking to do something like this: [image: fractions in a segmented picker]

edit: to be clear, I have the segmented picker code, but putting "1/8" in a label for each row item just displays "1/8" and I want the styling of a fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a service like the [unicode fraction generator](https://lights0123.com/fractions/) to build the fraction unicode expressions.

⅝ ²²⁄₅ ⅜

Comment: I knew it was going to be easy! Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`fraction-unicode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fraction-unicode)

```js
import fractionUnicode from 'fraction-unicode';

fractionUnicode(1, 2);
// '½'

fractionUnicode(7, 16);
// '⁷⁄₁₃'
```